# MassTransit high memory usage in cloudampq

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

We currently have approx 100 queues running in .NET Core 2.0, 3.0 and full .NET services using MassTransit all hosted in IIS on 2 servers i.e. 2 IP addresses/connections (and therefore 2 consumers per queue) and out memory usage on the AMPQ server is continually over 70% (approx 670Mb).

We have very low message counts at the moment.

Here's a screenshot of our consumer/channel count etc.

[image: RabbitMQ Metrics Screenshot]

I've looked through everything and can't see how I can reduce the memory usage, channels etc but they all seem really high. Any ideas on what to look for or what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

220 consumers, 300 channels, doesn't seem too far out of line. Connections look good, decent density of receive endpoints per bus instance, so that's good as well. *Are you seeing performance issues*, or just trying to avoid using 1GB of memory? RabbitMQ uses memory to optimize performance, so keep that in mind.

If you're on 6.x or later should be about as optimized as it can get, the newer versions use a single channel for receive endpoints, including messages sent/published by the endpoint, which significantly reduced channel usage. That only came into play during high request/response with temporary endpoints though.

I honestly don't see a problem yet – looks like good use of the application and services.

Comment: Just desperately trying to stay under the limit on our Cloud AMPQ service as the next jump u is 3x the cost and not sure we can justify that. We're only using v6 on a few services so perhaps it's worth us investing some time to update? And no we're not seeing any performance issues.

Comment: I agree with Chris - there isn't anything out of line here. Be sure you're using lazy queues. You may be able to save some RAM by doing some [TCP buffer size tuning](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#tuning-for-large-number-of-connections), though that may come with a performance cost. Best to tune and benchmark.

Comment: Yes, Lazy will save RAM, you can set it on the ReceiveEndpoint. The queues will need to be recreated, so clear them all if you change to Lazy.

Comment: I was a little concerned with the lazy queues going to disk and slowing down things (I didn't know for sure) but I think for some queues this might be OK anyway (email notifications for example). Will also look to migrate over to v6 over the next month or so. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Lazy queues are still fast, RabbitMQ just doesn't try to keep the entire queue in memory. All durable messages go to disk at some point, but are usually sent immediately to a consumer if one is available. Also, v6 no longer auto-starts the bus endpoint temporary queue, which may lower your queue count.

Comment: So I switched most queues to lazy and most of our APIs to v6 and the memory hasn't budged a bit. I even removed a lot of exchanges that weren't working. Strangely too when I shut off a few APIs as put of the update process the memory stayed more or less constant (around 660mb) even though there were hardly any queues. I'm beginning to think that something else might be going on!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post the actual solution to my problem no matter how silly/obvious it seemed. Thanks to @chris-patterson and @luke-bakken for confirming that the number of consumers, connections, channels etc all looked healthy I reached out to CloudAMPQ themselves who host and manage the RabbitMQ instance and they agreed that memory usage looked high. They moved our instance on to a new VM and the memory usage dropped to a steady 0.45Gb (from around 0.7Gb).